# Will Ubuntu MATE work on a RockPi 4?

Tags: raspberrypi, arm

Is ARM architecture, like Raspberry Pi, supported?

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SupportedArchitectures  (it doesn't mention *armv7* & *arm64* which are both supported if you follow links)

Comment: Googling ubuntu mate would be a great start - the website has a [link about RP](https://ubuntu-mate.org/ports/raspberry-pi/) on the main page.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu-mate website](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) has downloads specifically for Raspberry PI architecture.  You could download the install file, burn a USB  and give it a whirl...

Comment: The 20.04 image for Pi does not support USB booting; must write to an SD Card instead. It's fixed in 20.10.

Comment: @user535733 Learn something new every day...